# IIS 6 very page is preceded by default.aspx

Tags: asp.net, iis, friendly-url

I am using IIS 6 and we have site which is using Friendly URL..I am getting weird error 
all the pages are preceded by `default.aspx`. e.g suppose Page is `WWW.Test.com/blog` , the page is redirected to `www.test.com/blog/default.aspx`. Anyone faces this issue before?

Comment: I am assuming friendly URL is some kind of a HTTP module you have added ? or is it a wordpress plugin?

Comment: Its a CMS called EPIServer which by default converts the URL into Friendly..But why all pages are redirected to Page/default.aspx I don't understand.